# Android Data Binding ListView item fails onClick

Tags: android, listview, android-databinding

I have a **ListView** with this adapter :

**Adapter**

```
public class MenuAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    private List<ViewDataBinding> bindings = new ArrayList<>();

    public MenuAdapter(){
        FirstBinding binding = FirstBinding.inflate(inflater);

        FirstModel model = ...;
        binding.setModel(model);
        bindings.add(binding);


        SecondBinding secondBinding = SecondBinding.inflate(inflater);

        SecondModel secondModel = ...; 
        binding.setModel(secondModel);
        bindings.add(secondBinding);

    }

    ...

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return bindings.get(position).getRoot();
    }

    ...


}
```

**first.xml**(First layout for binding)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <data>
            ...
        </data>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/menu_row_height"
            android:background="@color/menu_application_background"
                >
    ...
            <Button
                 ...
                android:onClick="@{model.onClick}"
                />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </layout>
```

Actually this **onClick** is not working as expected...Clicking on button, it doesn't call onClick from my model..but after trying to scroll list..it calls onClick for all missed calls (ex. I can click on button 3 times in a row...but onClick is not called. After scrolling my listview, onClick is called 3 times(missed ones)).

What's wrong here ? Solutions?

P.S. Setting OnItemClickListener for ListView is not what I want.

Comment: data binding library is still beta. so bind data with holder will be better for now.